# Session variables on custom modules

Tags: forms, sessions

I have two modules. The first module is for custom login form and the other is for custom user pages.
I want to store a session variable from the first module and later to call on the second module. 
Let's say my field from the first module is:

```
<?php
function custom_login_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['custom_field'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => 'Custom field',
    );

   return $form
}
```

and this is the callback from my second module:

```
    <?php
    function custom_user_pages() {
       $The_session_stored_field = 'some_value';


    }
```

How can I store the custom_field with session and how to call it on the second module?

EDIT: My custom modules are connecting with web service and all the information I'm passing with `XML`. With `simplexml_load_string()` I'm getting all the data. Now I've used `$_SESSION`, but I have some error:

> "Exception:Serialization of "SimpleXMLElement" is not allowed in
>   session_write_close()...

EDIT2:In my first module I've set `SESSION` like this:

```
$_SESSION['custom_field'] = $custom_field;
```

On the other module I've set `$custom_field = $_SESSION['custom_field'];`

Is this a right approach?

Yes, I've got an error that's not related with session, because simplexmlelement cannot be serialized like that. Maybe I should open a new thread for that.

Comment: do you sure variable do your job? there is very different between SESSION and variables that store in db ???????

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've marked the answer too soon. I've edited my thread, so pls check that.

Comment: Your latest edit has got nothing to do with the `$_SESSION` and your initial question, but with the serialization of XML.

Comment: A `SimpleXMLElement` object cannot be serialized, as @Wtower says that's not a session problem - you'll need to cast it to a string first

Answer (score 1):

In submit of form store your data in session variable $sid with `_drupal_session_write('mysession', $value);` and in every where you want read it with `_drupal_session_read('mysession');`

you shold start session before you write or read session variable like php.

```
drupal_session_start();
_drupal_session_write($sid, $value);
_drupal_session_read($sid);
```

Comment: 'This function is an internal function and must not be called directly' https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/_drupal_session_write/7.x

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to make SimpleXMLElement object serialized by encoding it into JSON format (as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391553/55075)):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

This is especially useful for caching which usually fails, so the workaround is to do:

```
cache_set($cid, json_encode($data));
```

Alternatively find out if your service supports JSON format.